# JavaScript - forcing line to execute within a loop in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have a while loop:

`x = true; 

    while (x == true) { 

          document.images['id'].src = arr[i]; 

           i = i+1; 

           x = confirm('do you want to see more?') 

    }`

This shows me each image and then asks if I want to see more on firefox and ie, but in chrome and safari, it only displays the image after I leave the loop. I know this is efficient, but I'm wondering if there's a way to force execution of the line within the loop as I go along?

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a sequence of setTimeout instead of a loop to force the javascript user thread to stop and thus let the browser refresh the drawing.

```
var i = 0; // define outside showNextImage to be properly captured by it.
var showNextImage = function() {
    document.images['id'].src = arr[i]; 
    i = i+1; 
    x = confirm('do you want to see more?');
    if (true) setTimeout(showNextImage, 10);
};
```

Comment: I'm not at all sure this will actually solve the problem, because you're still updating the image and then immediately calling `confirm`. Pretty sure you want to use `setTimeout` *after* updating the image but *before* calling `confirm`, so you yield and let the page change get done. (Also, pretty darned sure you meant `if (x) { setTimeout...` rather than `if (true) setTimeout...`)

Comment: And actually, even if you do the `setTimeout` thing, you don't know that the image has finished downloading. So the timeout could easily occur before the image was downloaded, and so (as apparently Chrome isn't updating the page display when `confirm` is up), this may just make the problem more intermittent.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers:

1. Don't use `confirm`
2. If you really want to use `confirm`, yield to the browser after updating the image but before the `confirm`

#### 1. Don't use `confirm`

The best way is to not use `confirm` at all; it's antiquated and as you've found it behaves slightly differently on different browsers in terms of whether changes to the page are shown.

Instead, I'd use any of the 350,124 "dialog" libraries that are out there ([jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) has a nice one, but again, there are a ***lot*** of them), which work asynchronously and so you definitely see the page changes. Your loop would become an asynchronous function, but those aren't all that tricky once you're used to them and the benefits are enormous in terms of the user experience.

```
function chooseImage(arr, completionCallback) {
    var i = 0, imgElement = document.images['id'];

    ask();

    function ask() {
        imgElement.src = arr[i];
        showDialog(gotAnswer); // the nature of "show dialog" will depend on which one you use
    }

    function gotAnswer() {
        if (userSaidYes) { // Again, depends on the library you're using
            completionCallback(i); // Tell the calling code which one they picked
        }
        else {
            // Is there another?
            ++i;
            if (i >= arr.length) {
                // No, tell the user
                /* left as exercise */

                // Tell calling code none was chosen
                completionCallback(-1); // Using -1 as a flag for none
            }
            else {
                // Yes, ask about it
                ask();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. Use `confirm` but yield

The issue is that `confirm` brings things to a screeching halt while the browser asks the user a question. Changes you've made to the page may not show up while the confirm window is active (as you've seen).

If you really want to use `confirm`, you can still do that, just yield back to the browser briefly first so that it has time to show the page changes. **Note**, though, that this still may not be a guarantee, if the image takes a long time to download.

```
function chooseImage(arr, completionCallback) {
    var i = 0, imgElement = document.images['id'];

    showAndHandOff();

    function showAndHandOff() {
        imgElement.src = arr[i];
        setTimeout(ask, 0);
    }

    function ask() {
        if (confirm('do you want to see more?')) {
            ++i;
            if (i >= arr.length) {
                alert("Sorry, there aren't any more.");
                completionCallback(-1);
            }
            else {
                showAndHandOff();
            }
        }
        else {
            completionCallback(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var x = true,  
  i = 0,  
  fn = function() {  
    document.images['id'].src = arr[i];  

    x = confirm('do you want to see more?');  
    if ( x ) {  
      i = i+1;  
      setTimeout(fn, 0)  
    }  
  };  
fn();
```